# How can I fix my CLion installation?

Tags: clion

I can successfully run `/opt/clion-2017.2.1/bin/clion.sh` from where I installed it but how do I update what is shown in the launcher? In the launcher it still links to the old 2017.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Tools` menu of the new installation create new `desktop` and `command line` launcher and accept to override the old ones when asked by the process. This will override the former configurations and point to the knew configuration for the update.